# Orient DB 3.0.18: Compression with name 'snappy' is absent

Tags: orientdb, snappy

I am trying to open a database using Orient DB 3.0.18 created using Orient DB v2.2.37, however, the error "Compression with name 'snappy' is absent is outputted". How does one register snappy compression with Orient V3? I tried org.xerial.snappy in the maven POM, but no joy. Thanks in advance.

```
2019-04-22 21:44:20 t.c.s.a.d.Services [DEBUG] error:stop:com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityException: Compression with name 'snappy' is absent
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityException: Compression with name 'snappy' is absent
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.compression.OCompressionFactory.getCompression(OCompressionFactory.java:79)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cluster.v0.OPaginatedClusterV0.init(OPaginatedClusterV0.java:1547)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cluster.v0.OPaginatedClusterV0.configure(OPaginatedClusterV0.java:154)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.createClusterFromConfig(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:4804)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.openClusters(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:519)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:388)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBEmbedded.open(OrientDBEmbedded.java:281)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:903)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPooled.internalOpen(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:440)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.openDatabase(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:303)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:261)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.<init>(OrientBaseGraph.java:172)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.<init>(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:78)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.<init>(OrientGraph.java:137)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory$1.getGraph(OrientGraphFactory.java:87)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory.getTx(OrientGraphFactory.java:224)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution for those using Orient DB in embedded mode is as follows:

1) download OSnappyCompression.java from Orient DB Github repo and incorporate into your project

2) add the following lib to your Maven pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
     <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.7.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

3) register Snappy compression method as follows prior to start of Orient DB

```
 OCompressionFactory.INSTANCE.register(new OSnappyCompression());
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this compression was removed. You have to convert the database into a non-compressed version.

Comment: Andrey, its impractical since there are many databases where this compression is being applied and on different workstations. Is there a way to put it back? Why is that the OrientDB team has such poor respect for backwards compatibility?

Comment: @jamie Please do not put -1 for answer not because it is not correct, but because you do not like the result of the answer. Next time I will ignore your questions.

Comment: My apologies. You're correct that I don't like the answer. I don't see how Orient DB team expects people to use their database, when each time there is a major release, compatibility is broken.